# Restore data dumped from an Oracle database instance to a SQL Server database instance?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, import

I would like to know the steps on how to restore data dumped from an Oracle database to a SQL Server database?

Our purpose is to get data from an external Oracle database out of our organization. Due to security concern, the team that manages data source refused us to transfer data through ODBC server link. They dumped the selected tables that we need so we can restore the data in our organization. Each table's data files include .sql file to create table and constraints, a ".ctl" file, one or multiple ".ldr" files.

An extra trouble is: one of the tables contains a blob column, which stores a lot of binary data files, such as PDF etc.. This column takes most of the size of our dumped files. Otherwise I could ask them to send us data in excel directly.

Can someone give me a suggestion about what route we should take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either get them to export the data in an open format, or load it into an Oracle instance you have full control over.  .ctl and .ldr files looks like they used the old [SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm).